# Powershell parameter usage with net.ipaddress data type error

Tags: .net, powershell, parameters

I have a powershell function that takes a parameter like this:

```
    function whatever {
    param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Net.IPAddress]
    $ip1,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Net.IPAddress]
    $ip2
    )
    }
```

I am getting an error calling

```
    whatever("1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2")
```

The error I get is

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ip1'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Net.IPAdd
ress".

I have also tried setting a var to be something like

```
    $ipaddr=[Net.IPAddress]("1.1.1.1")
```

but it yields the same error.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing an array of string to your function arguments are passed using spaces in powershell   `whatever "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2"`

Answer (score 4):

Rerun is correct. This is a common tripping point when learning PowerShell because calling functions in most other languages requires parenthesis.

In addition to rerun's answer, you can also call your function with named parameters like this:

```
whatever  -ip2 2.2.2.2 -ip1 1.1.1.1
```

If you noticed I swapped the order of the two parameters. This is the advantage of named parameters, the order does not matter. rerun's example uses positional parameters, in which the order does matter.